# Navigate to a route if no URL params specified

Tags: angular, angular-routing

In my Angular 4 app I have a Groups section. It can either show a list of all your current groups (`/groups`), or show a specific group page (`/groups/21`, being `21` the group ID).

For that reason, I want to enable **routing to both pages from the same route**.

I have tried the following:

```
{ path: 'groups/:groupid', component: GroupPageComponent, resolve: { group: GroupResolver } },
```

It works fine when I navigate to a specific group, but when I try to navigate to the general 'all groups' page, it will just redirect to the default `'*'` match and not even load the `GroupResolver`.

How can I enable navigation to 'all groups' page if there is no group ID specified in the URL?

Comment: use a navigation api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify two routes:

```
{ 
   path: 'groups', 
   component: GroupPageComponent, 
   resolve: { group: GroupResolver }
},
{ 
   path: 'groups/:groupid', 
   component: GroupPageComponent, 
   resolve: { group: GroupResolver }
},
```

OR you could use only one route, the one with the id, and pass a value in, like 0 or -1, when there is no group Id. I use this technique on my edit pages to deal with editing a "new" product.

OR you could make the groupId an optional parameter. But that would change what your URL looks like: `http://localhost:3000/groups;groupid=7`which may not be desired.

[image]

Comment: This is better than the answer I was going to write - I was including a parent (of course on reflection it wouldn't be necessary the principle is the same). However [here's a plunker demonstrating it](https://plnkr.co/edit/iuaq8UPgPP375AepIjIq?p=preview) if you want to add it to your answer. (You can edit out the parent component to match your answer if you feel it's necessary)

Comment: Good answer! I prefer the alternative with two routes. Because then you get cleaner URL In the browser field. .../groups instead of .../groups/-1.

Comment: Using 2 routes seems to be the best option.